# iteratively retrieving information contained in different rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe which contains post and comments.
Every comment has an id and a parent id (identifies the comment or post which the comment was a response to).
Posts only have an id, since they don't answer to anything.

| submission | id | parent id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| post1 | 1 |  |
| comment1 | 2 | 1 |
| comment2 | 3 | 1 |
| comment3 | 4 | 2 |
| comment4 | 5 | 4 |
| post2 | 6 |  |
| comment5 | 7 | 6 |

I would like to retrieve the id of the original post for every comment and obtain something like that:

| submission | id | parent id | ancestor id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| post1 | 1 |  |  |
| comment1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| comment2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| comment3 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| comment4 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| post2 | 6 |  |  |
| comment5 | 7 | 6 | 2 |

to do so I tried to loop from the end of the dataframe to the beginning, iteratively tracing back the parent_id of the parent_id until I found an empty parent_id cell.
On the test dataframe it works, but on the main one is too slow. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

Here my original code:

```
#creating a column for the id of the original post
df["ancestor"] = df.id
#obtaining the id of the original post for every comment
for i in reversed(range(len(df.id))): #looping trough the comments
  id = df["parent_id"][i] #variable to initialize the future loop
  parent = id
  while parent != "": #only looping trough comments
    df.ancestor[i] = id
    parent = df.parent_id[df.id == id].values[0]
    id = parent
```

Comment: Is the dataframe as neatly ordered as in your example: `post` -> `all related comments`, `next post` -> `all related comments`, ...? If so, then you could simply do: `df["ancestor_id"] = df["parent_id"].eq("").cumsum().where(df["parent_id"].ne(""), "")`.

Comment: Or, under the same assumption, if you want the actual `id` of the roots: `df.loc[df["parent_id"].ne(""), "ancestor_id"] = df["id"].where(df["parent_id"].eq("")).ffill()`.

Comment: I would like the actual id of the root post. Which is not just a simple number unfortunately (i8g2kwe for example). The submissions are not sorted this neatly. The only rule that applies is that a submission will be somewhere before its child and somewhere after its parent. I could also sort them by date, but multiple posts could be posted at the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this speeds things up, but using the [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) library might be worth a try:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df[df["parent_id"].ne("")], source="parent_id", target="id"
)

roots = set(df.loc[df["parent_id"].eq(""), "id"])
mapping = {}
for comp in nx.connected_components(G):
    root = (roots & comp).pop()
    roots.discard(root)
    mapping.update(dict.fromkeys(comp - {root}, root))

df["ancestor_id"] = df["id"].map(mapping)
```

- First read the `parent_id`-`id` combos as edges in a graph `G`.
- Identify the root nodes `roots` of the trees (`G` should be a forrest, from what I understand).
- Then build a `mapping` nodes -> root (via the components of `G`), and apply it to the column `id`.

Result for the example:

```
  submission id parent_id ancestor_id
0      post1  1                   NaN
1   comment1  2         1           1
2   comment2  3         1           1
3   comment3  4         2           1
4   comment4  5         4           1
5      post2  6                   NaN
6   comment5  7         6           6
```

Comment: it is exact, it is a forest like structure.
When I run your code, this error is returned:
'pop from an empty set'

Comment: @user18694315 Then `G` is _not_ a forrest: Each connectivity component of `G` would be a tree (one post and all its comments), and each tree would have exactly one root (the post). So, either I've misunderstood something, or there's something amiss in the actual data?

Comment: I'm analyzing reddit posts. There is a root post for every comment.
After your comment I checked and there was one single random empty row in the dataframe (out of a million + total) at index 14936. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive function to target the root id:

```
def ancestor(row):
    if df.loc[df['id'] == row['id']]['parent id'].values:
        new_dict = {k: [x for x in (vv for _, vv in v.items())][0]
                    for k, v in df.loc[df['id'] == row['parent id']].to_dict().items()}
        return ancestor(pd.Series(new_dict))
    return row['id']


df['ancestor'] = df.apply(lambda x: ancestor(x) if x['parent id'] else "", axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  submission  id parent id ancestor
0      post1   1
1   comment1   2       1.0        1
2   comment2   3       1.0        1
3   comment3   4       2.0        1
4   comment4   5       4.0        1
5      post2   6
6   comment5   7       6.0        6
```

Comment: It returns me this error:
IndexError: list index out of range